# Linq to NHibernate query comparing enum mapped as integer succeeds, but fails as equivalent criteria query

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I'm querying for ProductRisk, which contains a Status property, where Status is an enum. Here's the mapping for ProductRisk:

```
public class ProductRiskMap : ClassMap<ProductRisk>
{
    public ProductRiskMap()
    {
        Table("AccountManagement.dbo.ProductRisk");

        Id(x => x.Id, "ProductRiskID");

        References(x => x.AssociatedProduct, "ProductID");
        References(x => x.AssociatedClient, "EntityId");

        Map(x => x.Reason, "ProductRiskReasonID").CustomType<int>();
        Map(x => x.Status, "RiskStatusID").CustomType<int>();
    }
```

Status is an enum with four possible values. It's represented in the database as a foreign key reference to a lookup table. In my repository, I want to pull the ProductRisk objects with a Status of `Medium` or `High`. The following query in Ling To NHibernate works:

```
    public IList<ProductRisk> GetByClient(int[] clientIds)
    {
        return NHibernateSession.Current.Query<ProductRisk>()
            .Where(x => clientIds.Contains(x.AssociatedClient.Id))
            .Where(x => x.Status == RiskStatus.Medium || x.Status == RiskStatus.High)                
            .ToList();
    }
```

But if I use (what I think is) the equivalent query in the Criteria API:

```
        return NHibernateSession.Current.QueryOver<ProductRisk>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.AssociatedClient.Id).IsIn(clientIds)
            .Where(x => x.Status == RiskStatus.Medium || x.Status == RiskStatus.High)
            .List();
```

I receive the following error:

> Type mismatch in NHibernate.Criterion.SimpleExpression: Status
>   expected type System.Int32, actual type
>   FIS.AccountManagement.Core.Domain.RiskStatus

Why is that? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried removing `CustomType<int>`? I don't think it's needed.

Answer (score 4):

when i want to map enums to ints in FluentNH i specify the enum as custom type then this should do:

```
Map(x => x.Status, "RiskStatusID").CustomType<RiskStatus>();
```